# Regex expression to find a match based on two strings regardless of sequence

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I need regex that can find matches based on two strings.  The strings can be in any sequence and may not be next to each other.

This is functional but I was wondering if there is a smarter way:

(ranger.{0,150}cowboy)|(cowboy.{0,150}ranger)

Examples where it works:

The cowboy was made a ranger.

Not all rangers are good cowboys.

Comment: smarter way? how. what's problem with your own solution. I think its doing its job and its not complicated

Comment: This is very simplified example.  My used case has many I's and if you need to make a change you need to do it in multiple places per expression

Answer (score 0):

You might use the following regex in PCRE/Onigmo:

```php
(ranger|cowboy).{0,150}(?!\1)\g<1>
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/wmVgq5/1).

*Details*

- `(ranger|cowboy)` - Group 1: `ranger` or `cowboy`
- `.{0,150}` - any zero to 150 chars other than line break chars, as many as possible
- `(?!\1)\g<1>` - match Group 1 pattern but not if the value immediately to the right is the current Group 1 value. So, if Group 1 matched `ranger`, this pattern cannot match it and only matches a `cowboy`.

Comment: This is really slick but will not work in Java.

Comment: @BJM Surely it won't, this is not Java compatible. Your question does not mention the language, nor the regex library, hence you got a generic answer.